# convert json payload to multipart content-type request using dataweave

Tags: mule, multipart, dataweave

having issue adding headers with uriparams,methods and unable to loop through array and unable to add multiple boundaries.
Input:

```
[{
        "add": 1,
        "city": "hyd"
    },
    {
        "add": 2,
        "city": "Kol"
    }
]
```

**expecting output:**

```
POST/test/api
HTTP Request Headers:

Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Accept:application/json
OData-Version:4.0
OData-MaxVersion:4.0
If-None-Match:null
```

HTTP Request Body:

```
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_8a6f6ebe-e9c9-44a2-b980-c33a69370eb4

--changeset_8a6f6ebe-e9c9-44a2-b980-c33a69370eb4
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 1

POST/info/post  HTTP/1.1
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft.OData.Client/7.5.4

{
“address”: 1,
“city”: “hyd”
}

--changeset_8a6f6ebe-e9c9-44a2-b980-c33a69370eb4
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 2

POST /info/post HTTP/1.1
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft.OData.Client/7.5.4

{
“address”: 2,
“city”: “kol”
}
--changeset_8a6f6ebe-e9c9-44a2-b980-c33a69370eb4
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: 3

PATCH/info/post (address='1',city =kol)?cross-company=true  HTTP/1.1
OData-Version: 4.0
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal
Accept-Charset: UTF-8
User-Agent: Microsoft.OData.Client/7.5.4

{
  "ready": "Yes"
}
--changeset_8a6f6ebe-e9c9-44a2-b980-c33a69370eb4--
--batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b—
```

Comment: You are trying to implement an OData batch request. Does the server support OData 4.01?

Comment: Yes server supports and this is OData batch request.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of requests would be very difficult to implement with DataWeave. It does support application/mixed but it doesn't support application/http parts. I'm not sure that embedding a multipart/mixed inside another multipart/mixed is possible.

Fortunately since the intent is to implement an OData batch request, since OData 4.01 batch requests can be made in plain JSON which is very well supported in DataWeave.

See more details on how to write JSON batch requests:

- http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.01/cs01/odata-json-format-v4.01-cs01.html#_Toc499720627
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/odatalib/json-batch

Comment: OData-MaxVersion it supports is 4.0

Comment: I asked specifically if it supported 4.01. If it doesn't then you will need to create the requests manually somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two custom dataweave formats ([like this](https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-custom-data-format)) for `multipart/mixed` and `application/http` in java if this is something you need to solve. This is a labor intensive approach!

Then you can use the [write](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-core-functions-write) function in dataweave to compose the `multipart/mixed` out of parts that are `application/http`.  It would end up looking something like this:

```
output application/mixed
var part1 = {
  method: "POST",
  path: "/info/post",
  headers: {
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0"
  },
  contentType: "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal",
  body: {
    address: 2,
    city: “kol”
  }
}
var part2 = {
  method: "PATCH",
  path: "/info/post (address='1',city =kol)?cross-company=true",
  headers: {
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0"
  },
  contentType: "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal",
  body: {
    ready: "Yes"
  }
}
---
[ write(part1, "application/http"), write(part2, "application/http") ]
```

Honestly there really should be an OData Client connector, but I haven't found one so far.